# GVIM : Shortcut for finding end for particular begin in SystemVerilog language

Tags: vim, gvim

Need a shortcut for finding the `end` for a particular `begin` in [SystemVerilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemVerilog) syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`vim` has a `matchit` package which lets the `%` key in command mode jump from a `begin` to the matching `end`, from a `<tag>` to the matching `</tag>`, etc. just as it does by default with matching braces, brackets, parentheses, etc.

To use it, you can enable the `matchit` package with

```
:packadd! matchit
```

Then define the matching words with

```
:let b:match_words = '\<begin\>:\<end\>,\<module\>:\<endmodule\>'
```

To use it, put the cursor on a `begin` or `end` while in command mode and press `%` -- it will jump to the matching `end`/`begin`. Press `%` again to jump back to where you started from.

You can put those commands in your `~/.vimrc` (or `~/.gvimrc`). Notice that the `matchit` package won't work if you're using vim in vi-compatible mode (with `:set compatible`).

More info is available with `:h matchit`, especially about how `matchit` interacts with the `syntax` mechanism.